# Architecture for image tagging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url, tagging

I am not getting further since days with the best structure to choose for my purpose. I have:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :description, :name, :image, :tag_ids

  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Then:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :images, :through => :taggings
end
```

And:

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :image
  belongs_to :tag
  attr_accessible :image_id, :tag_id
end
```

I have three main categories for now, all images belong into 'Solar System', 'Milky Way' or 'Universe'. Let's say I have an image of Saturn, so I tag it 'Saturn' and 'Solar System'. An image of a moon of saturn will further be tagged with 'Moon'. An image of Andromeda Galaxy will be tagged 'Universe' and 'Galaxy'.

If I want to display all images e.g. of the Solar System with the url:
www.website.com/solarsystem

There shall be links to e.g. Jupiter or Saturn. If I click Saturn the url shall be:
www.website.com/solarsystem/saturn
...and it shall display all images tagged with 'Saturn'.

The category structure (which will also be displayed) as a link shall in this case be:

Home > Solar System > Saturn

All categories are clickable and lead you to the images of the category. With the Image, Tag and Tagging model I find it very difficult to achieve all this. E.g. in /image/show.html I have problems to display the correct links of the category structure since they depend on the tag of the image. E.g. I need to say if tag.name = 'Saturn' then the 1st link shall be "Solar System". If tag.name = 'Galaxy', then the 1st link shall be "Universe". But with many tags and combinations it gets quite confusiong. Also the correct url (www.website.com/solarsystem/saturn) is not easy for me to achieve.

Is there a good solution, maybe with another model structure, maybe having an own model for all tags like 'Saturn' or 'Jupiter'?